# Can only navigate to a page once, then I receive 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

Earlier I had someone help me with a `.htaccess` issue so that I could remove `index.php` from the url.  However, while that seemed to work, I'm not sure if it fully worked unless it's something I'm doing wrong (likely - new to PHP/CI/WAMP, just started writing this Friday).

I'm using CI and WAMP on a Windows 7 machine.  Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

The base url that I go to to see the site is:

```
localhost/forum/
```

I have some menu items across the top.  One them them is `Forum` and when it's written out, the link is:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

I do not have the base_url set in my config file.  But when I hover over the link, it shows:

```
localhost/Forum/
```

When I inspect the element in Chrome it shows:

```
<a href="http://localhost/Forum/">
```

I have a div that is a link to what will be a sub-forum.  In the html, it's written as:

```
<a href='$record->name/'>
```

When I hover over the div, it shows that it will go to:

```
localhost/Forum/Site/
```

When I inspect the element it says it is going to:

```
<a href="Site/">
```

Now, for a minute there, I could start up Mozilla or Chrome, click on Site and it would go to where I wanted it to.  I could then click on Forum and it would go back.  But if I clicked on Site again, it would go to a 404 page.  Then if I closed the browser and opened it back up, it would work again one time through, then do the same thing.  I have NO idea what is going on here.  As I was typing this, I set my base url to `http://localhost/Forum` and even that didn't do anything.

## UPDATE

I edited my base_url and fixed the issue.  I was forgetting a `/` at the end.

Comment: Have you inspected the link element after you've gone to the forum and back?  Or just before you first test?

Comment: Can you remove the .htaccess file and make sure the linking works before it's implementation? Also, Can you verify that they linking breaks down in your sub pages? Did you verify the link (when you hover over it) the second time through?  I'm curious if the link the second time through reads something like localhost/forum/forum/site

Comment: @TheOx - I accidentally inspected the element when the code was `<a href='".base_url()."'$record->name/'>`.  I updated my post to show that inspecting the element shows `<a href="Site/">`.  But when I click on Site, then Forum and I check everything again, it all looks to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `site_url()` instead. `base_url()` is primarily used for linking to media such as Javascript and CSS.

i.e.

```
<a href="<?= site_url('forum'); ?>">Forum</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?= site_url('forum/' . $Category->CategoryID . '/' . url_title($Category->Title)); ?>"><?= $Category->Title; ?></a>
```

See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html for more information.

HTH

Comment: Actually, I found the issue.  My base_url() didn't have a `/` at the end of it.  My co-worker found it for me.